# Open only next div on click in one function

Tags: angular

How to open only next div on click in one function? I got stuck with it, example:

```
<div class="row">
 <div (click)="click()" class="div-one">
 </div>
 <div *ngIf="opened" class="div-open">
 </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
 <div (click)="click()" class="div-one">
 </div>
 <div *ngIf="opened" class="div-open">
 </div>
</div>
```

Something like this. If I have multiple rows, I only want to open only the next one, inside the same parent div. Thanks in advance

Comment: Every row should be a component, then you can set the "opened" var on each click and everything will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `*ngFor` and add an additional property to that array called `opened`

```
items = [{........, "opened" : false}]
```

then change that property to open the div

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let item of items">
 <div (click)="item.opened = !item.opened" class="div-one">
 </div>
 <div *ngIf="item.opened" class="div-open">
 </div>
</div>
```